# Creating an array with the amount of occurrences from an input file (C)

Tags: c, arrays, function

I've been working tirelessly on this assignment, it's already past due and I cannot for the life of me find a solution. We are behind on lecture and the professor still decided it was okay for us to do homework that we haven't even covered yet.

So this is the main function I've been having problems with. The goal is to read an input file full of integers:

```
12 15 7 1 19
18 16 15 2 8 
5 4 16 7 1 
19 4 16 15 3 
13 9 12 4 6 
9 2 19 13 15 
18 20 17 17 4 
3 12 2 18 18 
10 14 1 14 1 
7 10 18 17 18  30
```

After it reads the file, it's suppose to input the occurrences of each value into an array. So in index 1, there would be however many 1's there are. index 2, there would be however many 2's and so on up until 20. Index 0 will hold the total amount of integers the file contains.  The loop continues to scan until it reaches the integer 30.

The length I have set to 999 because the file will never be the same, so it will be kind of random and you'll never know the length. So once it counts through up until 30, I use 'amount' as a counter and then initialize length to equal amount.

For more instruction, this is part of the directions for this function specifically that was given by the professor:

> createVArray: This is a void function that takes three parameters: a FILE *  and an integer array and an integer indicating the length of the array.  Your function should read numbers from the file, one at a time, using the information collected to update the array. The first index of the array will be used to store the total number of votes read while each subsequent index will store the number of votes for that t-shirt logo option.  Your function should continue reading the file until the number 30 is encountered.

```
int array2[999], array[21]; //Global dec

void createVArray(int amount, int length){
int counter, i, j, m;
length = 999;
amount = 0;

for(counter = 1; counter < length; counter++){
    fscanf(votesFileptr, "%d", &array[counter]);

            if(array[counter] == 30){
                for (i = 1, j = 0; i < amount, j < amount; i++, j++){
                    array2[j] = array[i];
                }
                break;
            }
            for(m = 0; m < length; m++){
                if (array[m] > 0){
                    printf("Occurs %d\n", array[m]);
                }
            }
    amount++;
}

length = amount;
array[0] = amount;
for(i = 0; i < 21; i++){
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: I think your function declaration is not what the teacher asked for a start

Comment: Where are array declarations ? Are they global ?

Comment: @ameyCU Yes, I'm sorry. Forgot to through them in there. Edited

Comment: @KyleSteward In your whole question there is nothing described about "what problem are your facing?".

Comment: @ameyCU Adding the occurrences straight into the array after checking it's value. I had it done using separate functions before. Then I had to narrow it down to all in this function (professors orders) and I've messed everything up and am completely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

let's start simple

> createVArray: This is a void function that takes three parameters: a FILE * and an integer array and an integer indicating the length of the array

```
void createVArray(FILE* input, int counts[], const int length )
```

> Your function should read numbers from the file, one at a time, using the information collected to update the array

```
fscanf(input, "%i", &number)
```

> The first index of the array will be used to store the total number of votes read while each subsequent index will store the number of votes for that t-shirt logo option

```
++counts[0];
++counts[numbers];
```

> Your function should continue reading the file until the number 30 is encountered

```
if( number == 30 ) return; // or break if you want to
```

Appart from some loops, additional tests and check you should have the pieces to write your function already

and if you are really desperate : http://pastebin.com/bfNTKVHq

bonus : https://godbolt.org/g/F9GYI0

Comment: This helped me so much. I was just about to submit it unfinished but you gave me hope! After a plugged that in I got on a roll and finished pretty quickly. Thanks!

Comment: I though it was already past due, I was only helping you solve afterward, to help you understand, not to give you extra marks.

Comment: It was due at 11:30pm (currently 3:35AM). We are allowed to give her a printed copy with commented code explaining what we were stuck on and why it was late.

Comment: I hope you will say that stackoverflow helped you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm bored. From the spec you posted, I think your prof wants something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void createVArray(FILE * fin, int *a, int len){
    int i;
    assert(len>29);
    while(1){
    if(fscanf(fin,"%d",&i) !=1){
        perror("fscanf error");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(i>=30)
        return;
    a[0]+=1;
    a[i]+=1;
    }
}


int main(){
    int a[30];
    memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
    FILE *fin=fopen("test.txt","r");
    createVArray(fin,a,30);
    for(int i=0; i<30; ++i){
        printf("a[%d]=%d\n",i,a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

test.txt:

> 12 15 7 1 19 18 16 15 2 8  5 4 16 7 1  19 4 16 15 3  13 9 12 4 6  9 2
>   19 13 15  18 20 17 17 4  3 12 2 18 18  10 14 1 14 1  7 10 18 17 18  30

output:

```
a[0]=50
a[1]=4
a[2]=3
a[3]=2
a[4]=4
a[5]=1
a[6]=1
a[7]=3
a[8]=1
a[9]=2
a[10]=2
a[11]=0
a[12]=3
a[13]=2
a[14]=2
a[15]=4
a[16]=3
a[17]=3
a[18]=6
a[19]=3
a[20]=1
a[21]=0
a[22]=0
a[23]=0
a[24]=0
a[25]=0
a[26]=0
a[27]=0
a[28]=0
a[29]=0
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but we aren't allowed to use anything we haven't gone over. I already got a 0% on an assignment because I used something I learned last year. Basically the only header files we can use are stdio and stdlib.

Comment: Then skip the assert and make the array static.

Answer (score 0):

The problem presents the classic problem of accounting for the number of occurrences within a range. Any time you are presented with this type problem, you will capture the number of occurrences within an array having at least one element for each number in the range. (in your case `+1` since you are storing the total votes in the first element.

The next part is to loop over all values reading all values between `1-20` representing votes cast for the corresponding tshirt design. So if you read `13` you need to increment `array[13]` to note that 1 vote has been recorded for tshirt `13` design. Since you are reading numbers within the range of your array, all you need to do is insure you start with an array initialized to all `0`'s. When each number is read, you simply increment the value at that index by one. e.g. you read `12` to increment the vote count for tshirt `12` it is simply `array[12]++;` (or you could do `array[12] = array[12] + 1;` or `array[12] += 1;`, they all do the same thing)

During this time you are also keeping a running total of all votes, so every time your read a valid vote from the file, simply do `total++;` (or `total = total + 1;` or `total += 1;`)

Putting it together, you could do something similar to the following, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARSZ 21   /* array size 0-total, 1-20 shirt votes */

void createVArray (int *a, int n, FILE *fp);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int array[ARSZ] = {0};
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    createVArray (array, ARSZ, fp);   /* read values from fp */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    printf ("\n '%d' votes recorded.\n\n", *array);
    for (int i = 1; i < ARSZ; i++)
        printf ("  tshirt[%2d] : %2d\n", i, array[i]);

    return 0;
}

/* read integer values from 'fp' incrementing values in range `array`
 * for each value read and returning the total values considered in
 * array[0].
 */
void createVArray (int *a, int n, FILE *fp)
{
    if (!a || !fp) {    /* validate array and FILE stream */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid parameter in list.\n");
        return;
    }
    if (!n) { *a = 0; return; } /* validate length */
    int tmp = 0, total = 0;     /* read into tmp, increment total */

    while (fscanf (fp, " %d", &tmp) == 1) {  /* validate int read */
        if (tmp == 30) break;                /* if 30, bail       */
        if (0 < tmp && tmp <= 20)            /* if vote increment */
            total++, a[tmp]++;       /* total and value at a[tmp] */
    }
    a[0] = total;        /* set first element to hold total votes */
}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/votes.dat
12 15 7 1 19
18 16 15 2 8
5 4 16 7 1
19 4 16 15 3
13 9 12 4 6
9 2 19 13 15
18 20 17 17 4
3 12 2 18 18
10 14 1 14 1
7 10 18 17 18  30
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/tshirtvote <dat/votes.dat

 '50' votes recorded.

  tshirt[ 1] :  4
  tshirt[ 2] :  3
  tshirt[ 3] :  2
  tshirt[ 4] :  4
  tshirt[ 5] :  1
  tshirt[ 6] :  1
  tshirt[ 7] :  3
  tshirt[ 8] :  1
  tshirt[ 9] :  2
  tshirt[10] :  2
  tshirt[11] :  0
  tshirt[12] :  3
  tshirt[13] :  2
  tshirt[14] :  2
  tshirt[15] :  4
  tshirt[16] :  3
  tshirt[17] :  3
  tshirt[18] :  6
  tshirt[19] :  3
  tshirt[20] :  1
```

Easy to see, tshirt design `18` is the big winner with `6` votes out of a total of `50` cast.